# Comparing rows in a csv looping forward and modyfing them backwards according to their common values

Tags: python-3.x, loops, csv, iterator

New in python but I found no thread addressing my problem.

I have a BIG set of data I am postprocessing, which has been stored in a csv file where is already organised as a dictionary. Every datum represents a dot in a map that was collected from a unique point (centroid) if the dot was in a certain range. There is a list of possible centroids and their coordinates, where centroids always follow the same order. In some cases, several centroids are at range (50) from the same dot so I am trying to estimate which was the centroid that collected every point. The below code successfully calculates the centroids in range for every datum.

```
coordinates = ["41.49770104,-0.138334713","40.91960027,-1.841980944","40.86344385,-0.723219273"] #3 centroids as example

with io.open("Trips.csv", mode='r', encoding='latin-1') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile,  delimiter=",", quotechar="\"", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,dialect="excel")
            for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                label = ["Clat","Clong","Cradius"] #Centroid coordinates and distance to current dot
                result = []
                finalresult = []
                newlines = []

                if i != 0: #For avoiding 1st row (header)
                    for centroid in coordinates:
                        latitude = float(centroid.split(',')[0])
                        longitude = float(centroid.split(',')[1])
                        radius = haversine(longitude, latitude, float(row[12]), float(row[11])) #Formula not relevant for this case.Distance between points. Type: Float

                        if radius < 50: #Condition to consider a centroid
                            result = [latitude,longitude,radius]
                            a = dict(zip(label,result))
                            finalresult.append(a)
                        else:
                            continue

                    newlines = [row, finalresult] #New datum including possible centroids per datum
```

As the list with centroids always follows the same order and that order was used to collect the data my idea is to find a datum that has only 1 possible centroid. Then, moving forward from that row if the following has several possible centroids and any of them is equal to the previous one that one will be the right one. If not then the following centroid on the list will be chosen if available and so on. The same process goes backward.

However, as I am not reading all the data frame at once (as in a loop) I cannot see a way to compare rows and apply this criteria. Since the database is extremely big creating a new csv file with the centroid results is not feasible. Is there any way to compare two lines to include the aforementioned algorithm? I had a look on itertools and the function next(), but the latter does not work in this case: ("TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator"). Considering the row with 2 centroids:

```
                        if len(newlines[1]) == 1: #Only 1 suitable centroid
                        print(centroid)
                    else: #Several available centroids
                        finalresult2=[]
                        for centroid in coordinates:
                            latitude = float(centroid.split(',')[0])
                            longitude = float(centroid.split(',')[1])
                            radius = haversine(longitude, latitude, float(next(row)[12]), float(next(row)[11])) #next row
                            if radius < 50:
                                result = [latitude, longitude, radius]
                                b = dict(zip(label, result))
                                finalresult2.append(b)
                            else:
                                continue
                        nextline = [row, finalresult2] #next row'results

                        for c in finalresult: #Check if the common value
                            if c in finalresult2:
                                print(c) #Take the common value and apply it to the previous row
```

Why next cannot be apply to this list? Is there any way to play within the loop editing rows backwards if the following row has a common values with them?

Comment: Data processing at this scale is very inefficient with the `csv` module. I'd suggest using pandas

Comment: Learning panda right now. You where right.